# Extjs4 Upload file with just one button

Tags: file, extjs, file-upload

I want to upload a file with just one button "Upload button", which on clicked, opens file chooser, and if file selected, it must upload it.

The view should not show `input[type=file]` or any other labels, but just one button.

I know it is easy with jQuery or just javascript, but since I am relatively new to Extjs, I writing this here looking for your help.

Below is the sample file uploader from documentation. How can I customize it to fit my needs:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Upload a Photo',
width: 400,
bodyPadding: 10,
frame: true,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    name: 'photo',
    fieldLabel: 'Photo',
    labelWidth: 50,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor: '100%',
    buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
}],

buttons: [{
    text: 'Upload',
    handler: function() {
        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
        if(form.isValid()){
            form.submit({
                url: 'photo-upload.php',
                waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                success: function(fp, o) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `buttonOnly : true` is the config you need. It will hide the file path field.

Also use `hideLabel : true` to hide field label.

Include the upload file code in the upload file field event listener. 
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

I think my example will help you.. no need to click upload button once you select the
file it will sents ajax request.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Upload a Photo',
    width: 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    frame: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'photo',
        listeners:{
            change:function( thiss, value, eOpts ){
                  alert(value);
                  //here place your ajax request
            }
         },
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%',
        buttonText: 'Select Photo...'
    }]
    });
});
```

Note:Place your ajax request code in the listener

Answer (score 1):

file upload field

```
items:[{ xtype : 'fileuploadfield', 
anchor : '100%', 
emptyText : 'Select File',
name : 'fileData', 
fieldLabel : 'Select File', 
allowBlank : false, 
forceSelection : true 
}]
```

upload handler

```
function() {
    var form = Ext.getCmp('form').getForm();
    if(form.isValid()) {
     form.submit({
        url : uploadFileURL,
        headers : {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'},
        method : 'POST',
                waitMsg : 'Please wait...while uploading..!!',
                success : function (form, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Upload file..', action.result.message);
            Ext.getCmp('uploadWindow').destroy();
                 },
                 failure: function(form, action) {
                 Ext.Msg.alert('Upload file..', action.result.message);
                 }
       });
   }
```

};

hope it helps :)

Comment: The view should not show input[type=file] or any other labels. I want to make this upload action with just one button.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did when I had the same issue:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        items: new Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {

            buttonOnly: true,
            hideLabel: true,
            buttonText: 'Carregar Playlist.',
            listeners: {
                'change': function(fb, v) {
                    form.getForm().submit({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'carregaLista.php',
                    });
                }
            }
        }),
        //renderTo: 'buscaPlaylist'
    });
```

Hope it helps, cheers.